# Yelp dataset needed

Tags: dataset

I am writing a paper on aspect based sentiment analysis and I need datasets appropriate having only positive and negative classes to compare my result to other papers. Two of them are below which have used yelp dataset:
http://onlinepresent.org/proceedings/vol143_2017/41.pdf
https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-10-7605-3_78
If possible I would like to have access to datasets they have used, does anyone has them?

Comment: This is probably a better fit at [OpenData](https://opendata.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors of those papers?

Comment: @Imran Yes but half of their emails doesn't exist and the other half don't answer...

Comment: Sounds typical!

Answer (score 1):

For you to access the dataset you need to register with your email first. Available in both JSON and SQL Here you can access the dataset. [1](https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download)

Comment: I know that, I need to have the dataset they have specified not the large dataset present on yelp atm.